# TSQL - Alternative to Left Join in This Situation, Maybe a While? Help Needed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, datatable

ItThis is my original table Inventory(I):

```
LineId      Code    Detail
411642786   2AFD    NULL
411642789   1AFD    NULL
411642798   3AFD    NULL
411642799   3AFD    FREEDOM
411642823   A0DP    CLEVELAND              
411642835   A0DP    HERCULES                             
411642836   A0DP    PEACE  
411642839   A0DP    NULL
```

Which I am trying to assign a U-ID from this Table named Product (P) based on Matching P.Detail with I.Detail and P.Code with I.Code:

```
U-ID    Code2   Detail2
370392  1AFD    FREEDOM
370432  2AFD    FREEDOM
370480  3AFD    FREEDOM
370210  A0DP    [BLANK]
1258321 A0DP    CLEVELAND
625693  A0DP    HERCULES
943038  A0DP    PEACE
```

The code I've sed so far works for some of the possibilities but since it's a left join it's also bringing duplicated LineIDs into the current result:

```
I.ineId     I.Code  I.Detail   P.U-ID  P.Code2  P.Detail2
411642786   2AFD    NULL       370432  2AFD     FREEDOM
411642789   1AFD    NULL       370392  1AFD     FREEDOM
411642798   3AFD    NULL       370480  3AFD     FREEDOM
411642799   3AFD    FREEDOM    370480  3AFD     FREEDOM
411642823   A0DP    CLEVELAND  370210  A0DP     [BLANK]
411642823   A0DP    CLEVELAND  1258321 A0DP     CLEVELAND
411642835   A0DP    HERCULES   370210  A0DP     [BLANK]     
411642835   A0DP    HERCULES   625693  A0DP     HERCULES                   
411642836   A0DP    PEACE      370210  A0DP     [BLANK]
411642836   A0DP    PEACE      943038  A0DP     PEACE
411642839   A0DP    NULL       370210  A0DP     [BLANK]
```

Code that I Am Using at the Moment:

```
SELECT I.LineId, I.Code, I.Detail, P.Code2, P.U-ID, P.Detail2 
FROM Inventory AS I
LEFT JOIN Product AS P ON
  -- 1st Possibility:
  ((P.Code2 = I.Code) AND (I.Detail IS NULL) AND (P.Detail2 = '')) 
  -- 2st Possibility:
  OR 
  ((I.Detail LIKE '%'+P.Detail2+'%') AND (P.Code2 = I.Code))
ORDER BY LineId ASC
```

Any suggestions in order to avoid duplicated LineID and one of the conditions get validated without going into the next one?

Comment: @Eric . . . You have enough reputation to fix the code, so do it.  A new user to the site is not going to know the formatting conventions.  Showing or explaining what to do is much better than just commanding them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `outer apply`:

```
SELECT I.LineId, I.Code, I.Detail, P.Code2, P.U-ID, P.Detail2 
FROM Inventory I OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) P.*
      FROM Product P
      WHERE P.Code2 = I.Code AND
            (I.Detail IS NULL OR
             I.Detail LIKE '%' + P.Detail2 + '%'
            )
     ) P
ORDER BY LineId ASC;
```

This chooses exactly one arbitrary matching `Product` record for the result set.  You can add an `ORDER BY` to the subquery so you can get the latest or earliest or whatever-est record.